# What is the benefit of storing users in an IPrincipal/IIdentity?

Tags: c#

What is IPrincipal/IIdentity advantage as opposed to having a custom User class that contains the properties you need and using it for authentication/authorization?

Comment: They are interfaces, you don't "store a user" in an interface.  They have the usual advantage of interfaces, a contract that is not tied to a particular implementation.  Whether it is useful to have your class implement these interfaces is a bit doubtful, but unclear from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious benefits are as follows: the whole concept of application's authentication & authorization is built around principals and identities expressed as `IPrincipal` / `IIdentity`. Because of that, built-in mechanisms most often assume that these two are used. And if they are used, built in mechanisms can work.

Take web applications for example. The `HttpContext`'s user for a lifetime of a request is expressed as `IPrincipal`. By conforming to this convention you allow the authorization mechanism to correcly evaluate whether or not a user is allowed to access web resources. This is because both WebForms `UrlAuthorization`'s module and MVC's `Authorization` attribute assume the principal is stored in this standard way.

In desktop applications you have `Thread`'s `CurrentPrincipal` which is also an `IPrincipal`.

Replacing `IPrincipal`/`IIdentity` with your own authentication/authorization interfaces would take forever. You would have to rewrite most parts of the base class library that deal with authentication/authorization and instead of built in interfaces you would rely on your custom implementation.

But, I don't quite see any oposition between the two statements you presented. You asked about the advantage of `IPrincipal` over a custom class. But **`IPrincipal` is just an interface** (!!) and your custom class can implement it easily. The same with `IIdentity`. You can then have your custom classes put everywhere the `IPrincipal` is expected.

This can be slightly tricky of course, for example in web apps you would have to replace built in authentication modules that set up the `IPrincipal`. There are two used most often - the `FormsAuthenticaiton` that uses `GenericPrincipal`/`FormsIdentity` and `SessionAuthenticationModule` which uses `ClaimsPrincipal`/`ClaimsIdentity`. Your custom module could in contrast use any custom implementation you want.

Comment: "In desktop applications you have Thread's CurrentPrincipal" - in server applications too.

Comment: @Joe: true. I just wanted to give some examples, not the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

Standard authentication methods like Active Directory, the Windows Identity Foundation, and Windows itself all use `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`. Basically, if you want to use any of the built-in authentication mechanisms, you have to use those classes. Typically you'll have a custom database schema to store user information, and you'll create `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` objects from that data in order to do authentication.